# Visual C# - Service Runs On Windows 7 but not Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, service, startup

I have a custom service that runs alongside another application. The service manages the database that the application relies on. The application installs and runs perfectly on Windows 7 machines, but when running the application on Windows 10, the service does not start. When both installing and running the application I make sure to run them as an administrator.

Looking at the task manager, after the service has started and failed, the service shows but the status is "stopped". I have tried commenting out the functioning body of the code but the status of the service still shows as "stopped".

I have been stuck with this problem for a while now and debugging it is not easy. The program is being compiled using Framework 3.5. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

You can find the code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.Remoting;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp;
using Chant.Datatest.Database;
using System.Configuration.Install;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using Chant.Common;
using System.IO;

namespace Chant.Datatest.Server
{
    [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand)]
    public partial class DatatestDB : ServiceBase
    {
        TcpServerChannel serverChannel;
        CustomerDatabase m_database;
        ServerAdmin m_admin;
        AppSettings m_settings;
        System.Timers.Timer m_backupTimer;
        bool backupOS;
        int prevDay;

        public DatatestDB()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.ServiceName = "chantDBsvc";
            this.CanShutdown = false;
            this.CanStop = true;
            this.AutoLog = true;
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                m_settings = new AppSettings();
                BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider provider = new BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider();
                provider.TypeFilterLevel = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.TypeFilterLevel.Full;

                IDictionary properties = new Hashtable();
                properties.Add("port", m_settings.DBPort);
                properties.Add("secure", true);

                serverChannel = new TcpServerChannel(properties, provider);
                ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(serverChannel, true);

                m_database = new CustomerDatabase();
                m_database.EnableAutoBackup = m_settings.EnableAutoBackup;
                m_database.BackupCount = m_settings.BackupCount;
                m_database.SetFilePath(m_settings.GetOldDBPath(), m_settings.LogFilePath);
                m_database.LoadDatabase();

                RemotingServices.Marshal(m_database, "DatatestDB.rem");

                m_admin = new ServerAdmin(m_settings);
                m_admin.DatatestDatabase = m_database;

                RemotingServices.Marshal(m_admin, "DatatestAdmin.rem");

                backupOS = false;
                prevDay = DateTime.Now.Day;

                m_backupTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
                m_backupTimer.Interval = 5000;
                m_backupTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(m_backupTimer_Elapsed);
                m_backupTimer.Start();
                this.EventLog.WriteEntry("Chant DataTEST Server Started.  Database loaded from: " + m_settings.DBPath + ", Listening on port: " + m_settings.DBPort);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.EventLog.WriteEntry(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        void m_backupTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            m_backupTimer.Stop();

            if (m_settings.EnableBackup)
            {
                bool timeReached = TimeReached(m_settings.BackupTime);
                bool doBackup = false;
                if (timeReached)
                {
                    switch (m_settings.BackupType)
                    {
                        case IntervalType.Daily:
                            m_database.CopyDatabase(m_settings.DBPath, m_settings.DBBackupPath);
                            break;
                        case IntervalType.Weekly:
                            switch (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek)
                            {
                                case DayOfWeek.Sunday:
                                    if (m_settings.OnSun)
                                        doBackup = true;
                                    break;
                                case DayOfWeek.Monday:
                                    if (m_settings.OnMon)
                                        doBackup = true;
                                    break;
                                case DayOfWeek.Tuesday:
                                    if (m_settings.OnTue)
                                        doBackup = true;
                                    break;
                                case DayOfWeek.Wednesday:
                                    if (m_settings.OnWed)
                                        doBackup = true;
                                    break;
                                case DayOfWeek.Thursday:
                                    if (m_settings.OnThur)
                                        doBackup = true;
                                    break;
                                case DayOfWeek.Friday:
                                    if (m_settings.OnFri)
                                        doBackup = true;
                                    break;
                                case DayOfWeek.Saturday:
                                    if (m_settings.OnSat)
                                        doBackup = true;
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;
                        case IntervalType.Monthly:
                            if (DateTime.Now.Day == m_settings.MonthDay)
                                doBackup = true;
                            break;

                    }

                    if (doBackup)
                        m_database.CopyDatabase(m_settings.DBPath, m_settings.DBBackupPath);
                }
            }

            m_backupTimer.Start();
        }

        private bool TimeReached(DateTime timeIn)
        {
            bool reached = false;
            if ((timeIn.Hour >= DateTime.Now.Hour) &&
                (timeIn.Minute >= DateTime.Now.Minute) && (!backupOS))
            {
                reached = true;
                backupOS = true;
            }

            if (DateTime.Now.Day != prevDay)
            {
                backupOS = false;
            }
            prevDay = DateTime.Now.Day;

            return reached;
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            m_database.SaveDatabase(true, false, null, "");
            this.EventLog.WriteEntry("Chant DataTEST Server Stopped.  Database saved to: " + m_settings.DBPath);
        }
    }

    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public class WindowsServiceInstaller : Installer
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Public Constructor for WindowsServiceInstaller.
        /// - Put all of your Initialization code here.
        /// </summary>
        public WindowsServiceInstaller()
        {
            ServiceProcessInstaller serviceProcessInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
            ServiceInstaller serviceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();

            //# Service Account Information
            serviceProcessInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
            serviceProcessInstaller.Username = null;
            serviceProcessInstaller.Password = null;

            //# Service Information
            serviceInstaller.DisplayName = "Chant DataTEST Server";
            serviceInstaller.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
            serviceInstaller.Description = "Manages remote access to the Chant DataTEST customer database";

            //# This must be identical to the WindowsService.ServiceBase name
            //# set in the constructor of WindowsService.cs
            serviceInstaller.ServiceName = "chantDBsvc";

            this.Installers.Add(serviceProcessInstaller);
            this.Installers.Add(serviceInstaller);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing I find helpful when developing Windows services is putting the meat of the functionality in its own .exe or .dll, then wrapping that in a Service project. Besides just the separation of concerns, it also lets you debug most all it of it as a traditional app (running as the appropriate service user, if possible), since, as you say, debugging services is not easy.

Comment: Did you take a look at the EventLog, yet?

Comment: @khlr Yes I have tried commenting all of the places that it is used and it still has no effect on the outcome.

Comment: @A.Franklin Actually the meat of the code IS separated into separate namespaces (projects). If you take a look at the includes for example you can see that I am including the Chant.datatest.Database classes which are in a separate namespace (project). So the code you see in the onStart function is mostly just initializing the code in preparation for the "meat" of the functionality.

Comment: @Jmrapp Good job separating out the DAL into its own layer! I'd just take it a step further and separate out all business logic into a BLL DLL, too. The contents of `OnStart()` and `OnStop()` would be cut&paste into new functions in the BLL. The service would be as absolutely thin as possible, with only 1 line of code each in `OnStart()` & `OnStop()` to call the functions in your BLL DLL. Then you could create an equally thin WinForms project with Start and Stop buttons to call the BLL's new `Start()` and `Stop()` functions. It'd let you step through _most_ of the code you posted, at least.

Comment: I didn't say so explicitly, but most all supporting code would move to the BLL, too. Probably the `try...catch` could stay in the service. The goal would be to get as absolutely much code *out* of the service project as possible, since any code in there is code you can't effectively debug (plus it's just good practice under SoC). Sorry for rambling on, but best of luck in your debugging efforts! Sure can be frustrating to develop a service.

Comment: @A.Franklin Lets say that I did take the time out to separate everything into it's own layer. As of right now I have commented out the code so that only the basis of a service is present without any additional, functioning code. When running and testing the application with the service, it still shows that the service is stopped after running it. So even if I separated the meat of the code, it wouldn't make a difference as of right now because I already have it commented out. This only confuses me more because it's hard to understand what could cause the problem.

Comment: @Jmrapp Puzzling indeed! If you create a brand-new, empty Windows Service project, will that run on your machine? Sounds like you're already whittling the project down to a barebones state to corner the problem. Maybe starting with a blank slate and slowly adding parts in would reveal the issue (?). I know, I know, hardly groundbreaking suggestions from Captain Obvious here...

Comment: @A.Franklin I thought about trying this earlier, but figured it was something with the functioning code in the service so I never did. Now that I'm literally out of options, I might as well give it a shot. I'll give you an update ASAP!

Comment: @A.Franklin So a strange thing happened. This entire time I have been building the application and service on a Windows 7 machine and transferring the built application and service to a separate laptop running Windows 10. I decided to try building it on a Windows 10 machine and then transfer it to the other Windows 10 laptop and surprisingly the service works fine now. I checked the build numbers of the framework it was built with and the one built on 7 matches the one on 10. Is there any reason it works when built on Windows 10 but not 7?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116218/discussion-between-a-franklin-and-jmrapp).